# Is it possible to Develop a process for using a trigonometric function to successfully model any parabolic function?

Tags: conic-sections

Is it possible to develop a process for using a trigonometric function to successfully model any parabolic function?

I have tried doing this question however there are functions such as this one where I cannot find a fit to it.
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8jVy.png)
Equation: y=a sin0.703(x-c)+10

Comment: Define "develop a process."  Please give examples from elsewhere.

Comment: "a trigonometric function to successfully model any parabolic function": what ?

Comment: In what field $\ 0$ and $\ 1$ belong to?

Comment: Please do not try to completely change a question to something completely different after you have received an answer to your initial question. I have rolled back your nonsensical edit.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question, especially after it has received an answer. (Questions are free to post, you don't have to recycle!) I have rolled the question back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$, then yes, on any bounded interval. You can start with $g(x) = x^2$, develop a Fourier series (regarding it as an even periodic function on a symmetric interval about the origin), then use translation/scaling of $x$ and $y$ to move it to the desired function. The approximation will only be valid on a fixed interval.

Comment: Say example, I have the trigonometric function of y= -16 sin 0.3925 (x-1). What is the process of me getting the parabola of a half of a period?

Comment: No, it works the other way around. You said you wanted to model a parabola by trig functions, not model a trig function by a parabola. So *you* specify the parabola, and *I* will generate a trig function to approximate it.

Comment: A new question, how can I do if I want to do it the other way around, so having a trig function first then state a parabola?

Comment: @PhillipK you can evaluate the Taylor series of your trig function $f(x)$ (just until second derivative) at your chosen $x = a$ as long as $f'(a) = 0$ (meaning that $x = a$ is an extrema of the wave).

Comment: @poypoyan Thank you